# Transfer your app to another iOS Developer Account

Tags: ios, xcode

I’m developing an app in Xcode with my company's developer account. now I need to separate the account in which one for development and company account for distribution. I need to get the same bundle id that I used with previous account with my new developer account. How is it possible? .

[image]

Comment: You can't reuse a bundle id no matter even if both accounts owned by same person , all you can do is add your account as a team member to the company account this way those bundle ids will be available to you .